# Tex Live 2016 - Problem with tlmgr

Tags: texlive

i've installed Tex Live 2016 using `install-tl` in order to obtain the latest version, however i have a problem with the `tlmgr` command.
If i start the application with the command
`tlmgr -gui`
no installed packages can be seen: the obtained error is

```
Tk::Error: /usr/bin/tlmgr: open(/usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) failed: No such file or directory at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 416.
 TeXLive::TLPDB::from_file at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 416
 TeXLive::TLPDB::new at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 146
 main::reinit_local_tlpdb at /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 2024
 main::update_all_packages at /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 1970
 main::__ANON__ at /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 436
```

The `texlive.tlpdb` file is not installed in `/usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/`, but in

```
/root/texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
/usr/local/texlive/2016/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
```

How can I reconfigure correctly `tlmgr` in order to take the correct path?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try running:

```
sudo tlmgr backup --clean --all
```

Comment: For me, this produces `/usr/bin/tlmgr: open(/home/.../texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) failed: No such file or directory at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 416.`